# Increase the height of a nested(child) div to the occupy the height of its parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Example referred from "http://learnlayout.com/media-queries.html"

[The nav section here should span\occupy the entire height of its parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzVJK.png)

Tried setting the **min-height** to both "inherit" and "100%" both didnt workout.

Please suggest.

Comment: Show the code you have worked upon?

Comment: position:absolute; height 100%; excluding padding/margin reset

Comment: @nashcheez heres the entire css code

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent{
position: absolute;
height:auto;
}
.nav {
display: block;
width: 25%;
float: left;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid red;
position:absolute; 
height: 100%;
}
.section {
width: 75%;
float: right;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

Comment: @Dražen additionally also had to set the position property of the parents div to absolute since the child div was referrering to body\documnet as its parent. Thanks for your suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give navbar, position:absolute,top:0,bottom:0

Comment: worked, additionally had to set its parent div's position property as absolute. Even setting the height to 100% also works out. Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Some prerequisites have to be fulfilled:

1. Your child node must be styled with display:inline-block or block
2. Your parent must have a defined height as well